# Prevent checkin of pdb files on Visual Studio 2012 with TFS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We have recently move to Visual Studio 2012 from Visual Studio 2010. We are still using TFS 2010 and we use gated check-ins.
Since we started using Visual Studio 2012, when checking in VS automatically includes the pdb files from the output folder of one of our projects into the changeset.
Of course we can manually exclude them from the check-in, but this can lead to errors because if someone forget to exclude these files all the builds after the checkin will fail.

I do not want to prevent pdb files to being checked in, I just want to set the default as excluded. In fact in Visual Studio 2010 these were not even automatically added to source control as a change.

The strangest part is that if go to team explorer and "Add items to folder" by default all pdb files are excluded (which is the correct behaviour), so I don't understand why Visual Studio adds the pdb files on the output folder to the changeset.

**UPDATE**
After trying all the sugestions made the problem still exists. I've already removed the bin folder from TFS but Visual Studio 2012 continues to include DLLs in the output folder in the changeset. In the meantime we upgraded to TFS 2012 but the problem remains.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a tfs .tfignore file which you can add *.pdb files to in order to exclude them automatically. You can add this file at the folder or project level.

[Customize which files are ignored by version control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfs/ms245454%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#tfignore)

Another solution:

Assuming you have the necessary permissions,

1. Team Explorer right-click on the root server name, hover over Team Foundation Server Settings,
2. select Source Control File Types. A window opens listing all of the file types TFS recognizes out-of-the-box.
3. Select the file type(s) you want to exclude from source control and click the Remove button. Note- This is for all projects on the TFS server.

Comment: The first solution i've seen before posting the question. This only works for the checkin where the .tfignore is added (when the .tfignore is in the changeset). As for the second solution: the pdb does not appear in this list.

Comment: Actually if you place the .tfignore file at the root project level it will ignore all .pdb files in every folder.                                # Ignore .pdb files in this folder and all its sub-folders
*.pdb

Comment: I think you don't understand my comment... If i add this file it works for the checkin I make. For all the other checkins it doesn't work unless the .tfignore is checkedin again. I can't ask all the developers working in my company to include a .tfignore in all checkins they make. This has the same probability of failing as aking them to remove all the .pdb files in the checkin

Comment: If you add that file to source control you can ensure others on your team share the same exclusion settings.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not be checking in an output folder at all. If you did not check in the output folder, then you would not be checking in .pdb files.

Comment: I know that. I'm not checking in the output folder. Visual studio 2012 adds these files without me or my collegues asking that. The only .dll or .pdb that are on the TFS are third party libraries. Also this does not happen all the times neither it happens to all of our files on the output folder.

Comment: But this may be relevant... the project in question is an "old" "WebSite" from Visual studio 2005 (I belive this project type does not exists anymore) and the bin folder does in fact exists on TFS. But this problem never happen with any of the previous VS versions...just with 2012.

Comment: It's extremely relevant. Web site "projects" are different from everything else in Visual Studio! Exactly which folder contains the pdb files you want to exclude?

Comment: The folder that contains the pdb files is the bin folder of the website. The pdbs belong to the other class library projects on the same solution. The folder also contains an external .dll file that is under source control... don't know the reason but since I work here the file was always there. Should I remove the file and the bin folder from source control?

Comment: In general, `bin` folders should not be in source control. It's _source_ control, not _binary_ control.

Comment: Yes, I know that. Sometimes its hard to change working habits that people have. But I'm not against to add 3rd party libraries to source control, in fact I belive that is a common solution. What I don't understant is why this file is in the bin folder. It should be in another folder and the project that needs the library should have a reference to it. I will try to change this library to another folder (we already have a folder used to 3rd party libraries) and see if this solves the problem (probably will). However, something has changed in VS2012 in the way it handles this folder.

Comment: Everything referenced by the application, other than assemblies in the GAC, gets moved to the bin folder. Third-party libraries and such need to be in a separate "lib" folder that gets checked in to source control.

Comment: Taking the dll from the bin folder doesn't work. I moved the dll to another folder and deleted the bin folder from tfs. Visual Studio continues to add DLLs in the bin folder (the result of the project compilation) to source control.